# Helping with centering things

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wants to make a structure of: top, middle and bottom.
I wants that the top will be 30px from the top, bottom 30px from the bottom and that the text in the middle will be exactly the same distance from bottom to top (this is my main problem).
And of course that my goal that it will be adapted to all the resolutions.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Provide sample code/snippet.

Comment: Ah! The good old vertically centering things problem. So many solutions, yet we don't know which would work when :|

Comment: can you provide a picture?

Comment: @Ranveer it's a shame `{flex-align-everything-for-me-automatically: center}` doesn't have cross-browser support.

Comment: @ILoveCSS yep. Same with the newer ECMAScripts :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use absolute positioning.
You can play around with the [Codepen link here](http://codepen.io/MichielSteeg/pen/PbvqOV)

HTML:

```
<div id="top">this is top</div>

<div id="middle">
  <span class="full_center">middle is here</span>
</div>

<div id="bottom">bottom down below</div>
```

CSS:
The trick lies in the `.full_center` class

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#top {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}

#middle {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  height: auto;
}

#bottom {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
}


.full_center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `display:flex;`. It's the closest I could draw from your question. Here I used `background-color:red;` to show the `30px` distance from top and bottom.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.outer{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:red;
  padding:30px 0;
}
.inner{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:green;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
p{
  width:60%;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>This is text<br>
    This is text<br>
    This is text<br>
    This is text<br></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But one more question that I didn't understand, if I wants to write on top or bottom, how should I do it?

Comment: well first remove the `padding` from `outer` and then include your element of `height:30px;`